# How to refer to sprites when using Cocos2d collision detection?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Using the method below, how can one refer to specific sprites when checking to see if they intersect?

```
- (void)update:(ccTime)dt {
    for (CCSprite *sprite in movableSprites) {
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(sprite.boundingBox, sprite.boundingBox)) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

It appears that all sprites are available in the moveableSprites object, but I don't know how to check if specific sprites are colliding... I don't know how to refer to them.  If there is an easier way to perform collision detection I'm interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears your code above will always return TRUE because you are checking if the boundingbox of **sprite** collides with **sprite**, and since they are the same it always will.

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(sprite.boundingBox, sprite.boundingBox)) {//
        break;
    }
```

Should be comparing to a different sprite not the same sprite.

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(sprite.boundingBox, otherSprite.boundingBox)) {//
        break;
    }
```

If that does not answer your question maybe you are looking to avoid enumerating through the array?  If that is the case try using **tags**. Someting like below.

```
    CCSprite *aSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"hurdle1.png"];

    [self addChild:aSprite tag:2];
```

Now [self getChildByTag:2] can take the place of sprite
and you can just add boundingBox to check collisions, as below.

```
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect([self getChildByTag:2].boundingBox, checkSprite.boundingBox)) {//
        break;
    }
```